# Kibana 4.0 change default timefilter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

How can I change default time filter duaration in Kibana 4.0?
By default it is 15 minutes from now. It return default each time when I open new session Kibana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find index.js in [YourKibanaLocation]\src\public\index.js

and look for Timefilter() function (my Kibana version has it at string 115480).

After finding the function, change default value for timeDefaults to your liking and save index.js.
Mine looked like this:

*BEFORE*

```
function Timefilter() {
 Timefilter.Super.call(this);

var self = this;

self.enabled = false;

var timeDefaults = {
 from: 'now-15m',
 to: 'now'
 };
```

*AFTER*

```
function Timefilter() {
Timefilter.Super.call(this);

var self = this;

self.enabled = false;

var timeDefaults = {
from: 'now-24h',
to: 'now'
};
```

You don't have to restart Kibana after that, just refresh your Kibana page.

PS. Sorry for unformatted answer, I'll change later, when not on mobile.

Comment: The defaults in the current version have been moved to: <your kibana directory>/src/ui/public/config/defaults.js

Comment: @JohnD It does not make the change required in Kibana 4.6.1. I have answered that in this question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top right corner[Last 15 minutes]. You will get a dropdown from where you can change the time.

Answer (score 0):

In Kibana 4.6.1, the default time can be changed from 15 minutes to ,for example, 24 hours easily.

Location of file to change:

> kibanaDir/optimize/bundles/kibana.bundle.js

search for `'timepicker:timeDefaults'`, change the time from `15m`to `24h`, save the file and refresh the browser. You are done.